# How to remove the useless unconfigured items in matrix build of Jenkins/Hudson

Tags: hudson, jenkins, hudson-plugins, jenkins-plugins

I use Jenkins to configure my multiconfiguration build, which is like a snapshot.

The Axes I use are:

- **Labels**: *Mac10.6*, *Mac10.7*, and *Windows*
- **Platforms**: *Mac10.6*, *Mac10.7*, *WinXP*, *Win7*, and *WinServer2008*
- **Tasks**: _App_Installer_, *ATS*, and so on

It is clear that it makes no sense for *WinXP* to build on label *Mac10.6*. Although it is shown as diabled/unconfigured, it still confuses people.

So is there any way to remove the useless configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the matrix/multiconfiguration plugin there is a field to filter out the combination available from the combination checkbox.

If you want to only execute windows with windows platform :

```
label=="Windows" && (platform=="WinServer2008" || platform=="WinXP" || platform=="Win7")
```

Of course in your case you'll have to handle a huge expression but it's doable.

I hope this helps you!

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem. The workaround (by no means complete) was the following:

1. Separate builds for unrelated platforms (Mac, iOS, and Windows, for example) into different jobs.
2. Conduct a code review with the team explaining to them how matrix builds work.

But the truth of the matter that I also would like to see the matrix entries that do not pass the filter as blank, not disabled.

Comment: Thanks!  But the workarounds seem not attracted :).  Is this an open issue for Jenkins?